# SQL Server 2000 - Filter by String Length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database on a SQL Server 2000 server. This database has a table called "Person" that has a field call "FullName" that is a VARCHAR(100).

I am trying to write a query that will allow me to get all records that have a name. Records that do not have a name have a FullName value of either null or an empty string. How do I get all of the Person records have a FullName? In other words, I want to ignore the records that do not have a FullName. Currently I am trying the following:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Person p
WHERE
 p.FullName IS NOT NULL AND
 LEN(p.FullName) > 0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**make your data consistent first**:

```
UPDATE Person
    SET FullName=NULL
    WHERE FullName != ''
```

then query your data without worrying about inconsistencies:

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM Person
    WHERE FullName IS NOT NULL
```

IF you don't/can't to fix your data, you can use this:

```
SELECT 
    *
    FROM Person
    WHERE FullName != ''
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be the preferred way I suppose

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Person p
WHERE
    p.FullName <> ''
```

Comment: IS NOT NULL part is not needed - second part of where excludes such records anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about  ([ISNULL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx))

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Person p 
WHERE 
 ISNULL(p.FullName,'') <> ''
```

Comment: you don't need the ISNULL() because `null<>''` is false

Comment: That could be debatable X-) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259229(SQL.80).aspx